# Detecting supported Windows Operating System versions for built Inno Setup executables

Tags: inno-setup

I have two legacy installers of my program I kept on my website:

- One dated 2014
- One dated 2009

I usually only keep legacy installers because there was a change support of operating systems. But I can see no official documentation at my end to confirm this nor on my website.

Is there any safe way to determine what windows version these compiled installers supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what version of Inno Setup the installers were built with.
(use *About Setup* command in menu that appears if you click in window title icon)

[image]

---

And then check what version of Windows did that version of Inno Setup support in [Inno Setup version history](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is6-whatsnew.htm).

- Windows 2000, XP, and Server 2003 are not supported since [Inno Setup 6.0](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is6.0-whatsnew.htm#6.0.0) (2019-02-11)